# Confusion with order of transformations

Tags: transformation

Suppose if I need to transform $f(x)$ to $f(2x+1)$, the straightforward way is to do a horizontal translation of $1$ unit to the left followed by a stretch along the x-axis with a stretch factor of $0.5$

However, for $f(2(x+0.5))$, why do we perform a stretch along the x-axis with a stretch factor of $0.5$ followed by the horizontal translation of $0.5$ units to the left and not the other way round? I'm trying to reconcile the order of transformations with order of operations.

Comment: You can do things in whatever order you like so long as the final result is the same.  Walking three spaces forward followed by two spaces backward is the same as walking two spaces backward then three spaces forward for instance.

Comment: @JMoravitz but in the case of f(2(x+0.5)) if you perform the horizontal translation followed by the stretch you would get an incorrect transformation. [link]

(https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mhdnvgtasc). z(x) is the resulting transformation of stretch followed by translation, which is not the same as f(2x+1)

Comment: I did not mean to imply that you can change the order of things and always have the same result... just that there are multiple ways to arrive at the same result.  Shifting to the right $5$ units and then stretching by a factor of $2$ can also be described as stretching by a factor of $2$ and then shifting to the right *ten* units.

Comment: Similarly here... if you wanted to stretch and then shift by one unit or if you wanted to shift by half a unit and then stretch... both are perfectly valid.  If your question is why stretching and shifting by one is not the same as shifting by one and then stretching... that is as simple as noting that $2(x+1)\neq (2x+1)$

Comment: Yup. I understand that you can arrive at the same end result by following different transformations. what I am trying to understand is for f(2(x+0.5)), why is the order of transformation stretch first (with a s.f of 0.5) and then horizontal translation of 0.5 units to the left as opposed to translate 0.5 units to the left and then stretch.

Comment: Letting $a(x)=2x$ and $b(x)=x+0.5$ you have $f(2(x+0.5)) = f(a(b(x)))=(f\circ a\circ b)(x)\neq (f\circ b\circ a)(x)$...